# Can link be called more than once for an instance of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Are there cases in which `link` is called more than once for a `controller`?

```
angular.module('theApp').directive('theDirective', ['$http', '$interval', '$q', function($http, $interval, $q) {
    /* ... */
    return {
        scope: {
            onselect: "&onselect"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {/*...*/},
        controller: function ($scope) {/*...*/},
        templateUrl: function(element, attr) {
            return "/template.html";
        },
    };
}]);
```

So far have not noticed more calls to link than controller. But I am worried it could happen, do I need to add counter mesures in case link was called more than once for a controller?

Comment: Link function is called only once per directive, it has nothing to do with the controller.

Comment: @Shomz I understand `controller` is called once per directive. You are certain it's the case for `link` as well?

Comment: Well, it should be, by design. I didn't work on the project (but some people here on Stack Overflow did) so I can't make guarantees. Do you have any reason to this otherwise? Did you notice something strange with the linker?

Comment: I was just worried. After more reading about the directive lifecycle I now understand when the various functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Link can be called more than once if you are using `ng-if` or `ng-switch`.